# Quit out of test file on failure, but not entire test suite

Tags: npm, jestjs, mocha.js, chai

First of all, my terminology may be incorrect with some of these terms as I am very new to jest so if that is the case I would love to be corrected to help me learn.

In case I am using the jest terminology incorrectly, here is what I mean:

- **Test Suite** - The entire group of test files I am attempting to run
- **Test File** - The actual .js test file that is being run
- **Test** - The individual 'it' code blocks in each test file.

Currently, I am using a group of around 20 jest tests to test my API EPs for my SQL Server and its corresponding linked server.

To do this, I run an npm command like so in the terminal.

```
npm run test:file ape/linked -- --env=monke.env
```

With how jest currently is working, if one of tests in the 20 test files fails, then it quits out of the test suite entirely.
I would like it to just fail out of whatever test file it is in, then continue to the next text file.

I know jest currently has the --bail flag, but enabling this continues the same test file on failure which I can't have happen due to the nature of my linked server to my actual SQL server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am new to all of this so let me know if more info needs to be included.

This will be running on various mac versions as well as Ubunutu server

Comment: You'd think this would be a very common thing to do with jest...